# Hibernate doesn't change column for new parameters

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple object which I want save in DB. But for time it was necessary to change someone parameters. I drop my old table but when I turn on my program - Hibernate still create DB with old columns.

For example:

My old class looked like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tests")
public class Test {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private boolean isFree;
private int status;
private String author;
private String section;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "qTest", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {  CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Question> questions;
private String commentToAdmin;
...
and geters-seters
}
```

In table I have column "status" like INT.
But then I change this class parameter to String. Now my class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tests")
public class Test {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private boolean isFree;
@Column(name = "statusT")
private String status;
private String author;
private String section;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "qTest", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Question> questions;
private String commentToAdmin;

And geters-setters
}
```

But after drop old table and restart my application column "status" still "INT" and his name "status" (not "statust").

Please help me understand why it's happening

Comment: This might be a silly question but since you only say you restarted your application: Did you recompile and redeploy/install after the changes?

Comment: how do you generate the table's beans?

Comment: OH GOD SPIDERS , thanks! Now I am fill like idiot :)